# Expected value and variance of median

Tags: variance, expected-value, median

Suppose $Y|\Lambda\sim U(0,\lambda)$ with $\Lambda \sim U(0,1)$. If there is sample with size $n$ of $Y$ (To simplify, assume $n$ is odd, so $n=2m-1$). How do I calculate the expected value of median ($E[Y_{(m)}]$) and variance of the median ($Var[Y_{(m)}]$). Thanks in advance

Note: To clarify, my intention was that $\{ Y_1, \dots, Y_n  \}$ is generated with the same $\Lambda$ value (so there's only 1 value of $\Lambda$, not $n$ for each value of $Y_i$). Sorry for the lack of information on the previous post.

Comment: You can (easily) find the distribution of $Y,$ which directly gives the distribution of the median, and then apply the standard integral formulas, giving a three-step solution.  Which step do you need help with?

Comment: Why should it not converge? It is bounded between $0$ and $1$ and there is no reason to suppose it would keep changing direction as $m$ keeps increasing

Comment: Re-stated: Finding the mixture distribution of  is okey-dokey. Finding the distribution of the median is okey-dokey too. But, it seems to me the expectation of the median does not have a closed-form. Are you saying that it does?

Comment: @Wolfies By symmetry, the expectation of the median conditional on $\Lambda$ is $\Lambda/2.$ Thus, the expectation of the median of $Y$ must be $1/4.$ // The exact distribution of the median is straightforward to find, because it's a uniform scale mixture of Beta distributions.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I was trying to do it with ordered statistics, but the integral (to evaluate 1st and 2nd moment) does not exist.

Comment: @whuber The expectation of the sample median is only 1/4 in the special case when the sample size is $n=1$. Please see answer posted below.

Comment: @Wolfies That contradicts the answer by Zhanxiong, which uses a different method to derive the same result.  I think there must be a problem with your calculation.  I simulated the cases $n=3$ and $n=5$ before posting my comment, finding results indistinguishable from $1/4.$

Comment: @whuber: I agree with you, but to clarify the difference between the two readings of the questions try with $n=9$ in the R code `medA<-function(n){median(runif(n,0,runif(1)))}; simsA<-replicate(10^4,medA(9)); mean(simsA)` which gives about $0.25$ while
`medB<-function(n){median(runif(n,0,runif(n)))}; simsB<-replicate(10^4,medB(9)); mean(simsB)` gives about $0.20$.  Wolfies has $n$ different $\Lambda$ in each sample, while you and I and Zhanxiong have the same value through that sample

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Caveat**: The calculation below relies on the (not explicitly stated) condition that the sample $\{Y_1, \ldots, Y_n\}$ is drawn independently from $U(0, \lambda)$ once $\Lambda = \lambda$ was observed.  In other words, $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ are conditionally independent given $\Lambda = \lambda$. Note that this sampling mechanism is essentially different from drawing $n$ i.i.d. observations from the marginal density (as simulated in @wolfies answer) $f_Y(y) = -\log y, 0 < y < 1$. The closed-form solutions with the second interpretation should be much harder -- the density of $Y_{(m)}$ if $Y_1, \ldots, Y_{2m - 1} \text{ i.i.d. } \sim f_Y$ [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_an_absolutely_continuous_distribution)
\begin{align}
g(x) = -\frac{(2m - 1)!}{[(m - 1)!]^2}[x(1 - \log x)(1 - x(1 - \log x))]^{m - 1}\log x, \quad 0 < x < 1. 
\end{align}

---

Here we use that the $k$-th order statistic of the standard uniform distribution [is beta-distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Order_statistics_sampled_from_a_uniform_distribution), i.e., $U_{(k)} \sim B(k, n + 1 - k)$, whence $\lambda^{-1}Y_{(m)}|\Lambda = \lambda \sim B(m, 2m - 1 + 1 - m) = B(m, m)$.  It then follows by the [moments of beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) that
\begin{align}
& E[\lambda^{-1}Y_{(m)}|\Lambda = \lambda] = \frac{m}{m + m} = \frac{1}{2}, \\
& \operatorname{Var}(\lambda^{-1}Y_{(m)}|\Lambda = \lambda) = \frac{m^2}{4m^2\cdot(2m + 1)} = 
\frac{1}{8m + 4}.
\end{align}
Therefore
\begin{align}
E[Y_{(m)}|\Lambda] = \frac{1}{2}\Lambda, \quad
\operatorname{Var}(Y_{(m)}|\Lambda) = \frac{\Lambda^2}{8m + 4}.
\end{align}
It then follows by the law of total expectations and variances that
\begin{align}
& E[Y_{(m)}] = \frac{1}{2}E[\Lambda] = \frac{1}{4}, \\
& \operatorname{Var}(Y_{(m)}) = E[\operatorname{Var}(Y_{(m)}|\Lambda)] + 
\operatorname{Var}(E[Y_{(m)}|\Lambda]) = \frac{1}{8m + 4}E[\Lambda^2] + 
\frac{1}{4}\operatorname{Var}(\Lambda) \\
& = \frac{1}{8m + 4}\times\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4}\times \frac{1}{12} = 
\frac{2m + 5}{96m + 48}.
\end{align}

Comment: @wolfies of course not... Did you really understand the argument? Take $n = 2m - 1$ and $k = m$ in the first link in my answer.  Here $n$ can be any positive integer.

Comment: At its essence, your solution posits that the expected value of the sample median is a constant (independent of the sample size). I have posted a solution that asserts that it is _not_ a constant. It is very easy to check via simulation whether it is a constant, or not.

Comment: @wolfies I think the difference of your simulation and my calculation above lies in that how the sample $Y$ was drawn (the OP didn't sufficiently clarify it) -- my interpretation is that a sample was drawn given the same $\Lambda = \lambda$, that is $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ are (conditionally) independent $U(0, \lambda)$ given $\Lambda = \lambda$, while your simulation is based on the interpretation that $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n \text{ i.i.d. } \sim f(y) = -\log y$. I will clarify it in my answer.

Comment: It occurred to me too that this explains the difference. However, we both agreed that the unconditional pdf of $Y$ is $-\log y$, and that result is not consistent with holding $\lambda$ constant.

Comment: @wolfies Again, that depends on how you interpret the problem.  $-\log y$ is the unconditional pdf for **ONE** $Y$, but not the the joint unconditional pdf of $(Y_1, \ldots, Y_n)$ if we take the first interpretation, under which case the expectation is indeed $1/4$.

Answer (score 2):

As whuber has noted, this problem has 3 stages:

**Step 1: The unconditional pdf of $Y$**

The first stage is comparatively easy (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2598983/xu-u-sim-mathsfunif0-u-and-u-sim-mathsfunif0-1-are-x-u-are-ind) for instance) which is to find the unconditional distribution of $Y$, *i.e.* the parameter mixture of two Uniforms.

The unconditional pdf of $Y$, say $f(y)$ is :

[image]

**Step 2: The distribution of the sample median of $Y$**

The OP assumes that a random sample of size $n$ is drawn on $Y$ where $n$ is odd, and so we write $n=2r-1$.
The sample median, which we denote by $M$, corresponds to the middle order statistic in a sample of size $n$, which is by definition thus $Y_{(r)}$.

The pdf of the $r^\text{th}$ order statistic, in a sample of size $n$, can be found using the `OrderStat[r, f, n]` function in the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*.

The pdf of the sample median is then $g(m)$:

[image]

with domain of support:

[image]

**Step 3: The mean and variance of the sample median**

Calculating the mean and variance of the sample median does not appear to have an obvious closed form solution, as a general function of the sample size ($n$ or equivalently $r$). However, for given values of $r$, it yields exact solutions. For instance, when $r = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$:

[image]

Note that this is the mean of the sample median for sample sizes $n = 1, 3, 5, 7, 9$, and corresponds to numerical values of:

{0.25, 0.220486, 0.209634, 0.204037, 0.200629}

Variance:

Similarly, the variance of the sample median, when $r = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ is:

[image]

Note that this is the variance of the sample median for sample sizes of $n = 1, 3, 5, 7, 9$, and corresponds to numerical values of:

{0.0486111, 0.0242859, 0.0159245, 0.0117921, 0.00934636}

The following diagram plots the expectation of the sample median, for $r$ from 1 to 25  (corresponding to the odd-sized samples from $n = 1$ to $49$):

[image]

**Check by Simulation**

Here is some quick code to simulate: for any given value of $r$, generate 500,000 samples of size $n = 2r-1$. Then, for each sample, calculate the sample median, and then find the sample mean of all 500,000 sample medians:

> SimExpectedMedian[r_] := (data = Partition[RandomNumber[(2 r -
> 1)*500000, f], 2 r - 1]; Mean[Map[Median, data]])

For example, here we simulate the solution for $r = 1, 2, 3, 4$ and $5$:

[image]

... which very closely fits the exact solutions derived above (stated here numerically for ease of comparison):

{0.25, 0.220486, 0.209634, 0.204037, 0.200629}

The following diagram plots:

a) the EXACT expectation of the sample median derived above (for $r = 1$ to 25):  big **BLUE** dots

b) the SIMULATED mean of the sample median:  smaller **RED** dots

[image]

The simulated and exact results are so close that red and blue dots lie on top of each other.

Comment: I read the original question as saying $\Lambda$ is the same value for all $n$ samples of $Y$.  Repeat the experiment and  $\Lambda$ will change. You seem to read it as having $n$ different values of $\Lambda$ in the sample of $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

To contribute to this thread that has already seen very interesting answers:

**A.** The marginal distribution function of $Y$ is

$$F_Y(y) = y\cdot(1-\ln(y)).$$

To find the population median, we have
$$m_Y:= F_Y(m) = \frac 12 \implies m_Y\cdot(1-\ln(m_Y)) = \frac 12 \implies m_Y: 1-\ln(m_Y)-\frac 1 {2m_Y} = 0.$$
This implicit equation is monotonic and it is satisfied for
$$m_Y \approx 0.18668235.$$

This is **the median of the marginal distribution of $Y$**, and we see that the expected value of the *sample* median from draws from *this* marginal distribution (@wolfies answer), appears to tend downwards from the value $0.25$ as the sample size increases, so we can expect it to become unbiased at the limit.

**B.** The conditional distribution function of $Y$, evaluated at the *conditional* median $m^c_Y$ is

$$\Pr\big(Y \leq m^c_Y \mid \Lambda = \lambda\big) = \frac {m^c_Y}{\lambda} = \frac 12 \\
\implies m^c_Y = \frac {\lambda} 2.$$

Viewed as a function of $\Lambda$, this is a random variable, and so, **the expected value of the conditional median** is, (with $f_{\Lambda}(\lambda)$ the density of $\Lambda$)

$$E[m^c_Y] = \int_0^1 f_{\Lambda}(\lambda)\cdot m^c_Y d\lambda = \int_0^1 1\cdot \frac {\lambda} 2\,d\lambda = \frac {\lambda^2} 4 \Big |^1_0 = \frac 1 4.$$

We see that

- the "expected value of the conditional median"

equals

- the "unconditional expected value of the sample median drawn from the conditional distribution" (@Zhanxiong answer).

This tells us that the sample conditional median is unbiased for the population conditional median, already for finite samples.

--

**Why the difference in performance?**
Why, when we draw from the marginal distribution of $Y$, we get unbiasedness of the sample median only asymptotically, while when we draw from a conditional (without needing to know the value of $\lambda$, just that it has been fixed), we get unbiasedness immediately? Contemplate.